# COCOS2D. dragging CCSprite on the screen with ccTouchMoved makes the movement jerky

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have an issue with my ccTouchMoved method. I have 3 ccSprites what I want to be able to move around on the screen using my finger. The thing is that the movement is jerky and it sometimes even looses "the grip" of the ccSprites when dragging the image, if I move the mouse pointer to fast.

what am I missing?

the three touchmethods that I use have the following tasks:

ccTouchBegan : scale up the ccSprite that is being touched

ccTouchMoved : move the ccSprite that is touched across the screen

ccTouchEnded: scale down the ccSprite to it's original size and stop the movement (is there a better way of scaling down the ccSprite to it's original size?)

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

CCLOG(@"ccTouchBeganRuby");

CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];

if(CGRectContainsPoint([animatingRuby1 boundingBox], location)){
    CCLOG(@"ccTouchEndedRubyScaleUp1");
    id ScaleAction1 = [CCScaleBy actionWithDuration:1 scale:1.2f ];
    [animatingRuby1 runAction:ScaleAction1];
}
if(CGRectContainsPoint([animatingRuby2 boundingBox], location)){
    CCLOG(@"ccTouchEndedRubyScaleUp2");
    id ScaleAction2 = [CCScaleBy actionWithDuration:1 scale:1.2f ];
    [animatingRuby2 runAction:ScaleAction2];
}
if(CGRectContainsPoint([animatingRuby3 boundingBox], location)){
    CCLOG(@"ccTouchEndedRubyScaleUp3");
    id ScaleAction3 = [CCScaleBy actionWithDuration:1 scale:1.2f ];
    [animatingRuby3 runAction:ScaleAction3];
}

return YES;
```

}

```
- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event{

CCLOG(@"ccTouchMovedRuby");

if (CGRectContainsPoint([animatingRuby1 boundingBox], location)) {
    CCLOG (@"moveRubies1");
    if((CGRectContainsPoint([animatingRuby2 boundingBox], location))|| (CGRectContainsPoint([animatingRuby1 boundingBox], location))) {
        return;
    }
    animatingRuby1.position = location;

}
if (CGRectContainsPoint([animatingRuby2 boundingBox], location)) {
    CCLOG (@"moveRubies2");
    if((CGRectContainsPoint([animatingRuby1 boundingBox], location))|| (CGRectContainsPoint([animatingRuby3 boundingBox], location))) {
        return;
    }
    animatingRuby2.position = location;
}
if (CGRectContainsPoint([animatingRuby3 boundingBox], location)) {
    CCLOG (@"moveRubies3");
    if((CGRectContainsPoint([animatingRuby1 boundingBox], location))|| (CGRectContainsPoint([animatingRuby2 boundingBox], location))) {
        return;
    }
    animatingRuby3.position = location;

}
[self collidableWithEachOther:location];
```

}

```
- (void)ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *) event{
CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize]; 
CCLOG(@"ccTouchEndedRuby");
CGPoint location = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace: touch];

if(CGRectContainsPoint([animatingRuby1 boundingBox], location)){
    CCLOG(@"ccTouchEndedRubyScaleDown1");
    [animatingRuby1 setScaleX:screenSize.width/14850.0f]; 
    [animatingRuby1 setScaleY:screenSize.height/9552.0f];

}
if(CGRectContainsPoint([animatingRuby2 boundingBox], location)){
    CCLOG(@"ccTouchEndedRubyScaleDown2");
    [animatingRuby2 setScaleX:screenSize.width/14850.0f]; 
    [animatingRuby2 setScaleY:screenSize.height/9552.0f];
}
if(CGRectContainsPoint([animatingRuby3 boundingBox], location)){
    CCLOG(@"ccTouchEndedRubyScaleDown3");
    [animatingRuby3 setScaleX:screenSize.width/14850.0f]; 
    [animatingRuby3 setScaleY:screenSize.height/9552.0f];
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Take the vector from the sprite to the touch location and set it as the direction for the sprite, while limiting its speed. This way changes won't be as quick and drastic and the movement will look smoother. Don't require that the touch location always be over the sprite, just keep track of whether a drag operation is taking place, and which sprite is being dragged.

Comment: Sorry if I sound like a totally noob (I am a noob though) but I didn't understand how you meant. I'm still learning so can you please use a example to show me...